# Calculating stock returns in R

Tags: r

absolute noob here guys, so please bear with me. i have the following code to load data from a csv file and do some calculations. one of the calculations is just getting monthly returns for each stock. but i am clearly doing something wrong as I am getting the following msg:

```
Error in log(mprices) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I am putting up my code that I have written so far. Very basic stuff.

```
stockdata <- read.csv("NZXALL.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
# Converting to XTS
dates <- stockdata$Date
stock.xts <- as.xts(stockdata, order.by=as.Date(dates, "%d/%m/%Y"))
data <- stock.xts
data$Date <- NULL                                      #Remove Date field
mprices <- aggregate(data, as.yearmon, tail, 1)       #Convert to monthly prices
monthly.returns <- diff(log(mprices))                 # convert prices to log returns
```

Any idea where I am going wrong? The dataset is in the following manner

```
Date        StockX    StockY    StockZ...
dd/mm/yyyy  price1    price1    price1
```

There are currently 142 stocks and data ranges between 2005 & 2014

Thanks!

```
> dput(head(stockdata))
structure(list(Date = c("5/01/2005", "6/01/2005", "7/01/2005", 
"10/01/2005", "11/01/2005", "12/01/2005"), ABA = c(1.11, 1.11, 
1.12, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), ACY = c(3.61, 3.61, 3.7, 3.7, 3.75, 
3.75), AFI = c(3.89, 3.89, 3.9, 3.92, 3.92, 3.98), AIA = c(8.05, 
8.2, 8.1, 8.11, 8.1, 8.08), AIR = c(1.65, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.62, 
1.62), ALF = c(2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.65, 2.5), AMP = c(7.75, 
7.65, 7.75, 8, 8.03, 8), ANZ = c(22.3, 22.3, 22.2, 22.5, 22.63, 
22.6), AOR = c(0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03), APN = c(5.58, 
5.58, 5.58, 5.58, 5.58, 5.58), ARG = c(1.18, 1.18, 1.18, 1.18, 
1.18, 1.18), ASBPA = c(1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.05, 1.07, 1.06), ASBPB = c(1.01, 
1, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01), ATM = c(0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08), ATR = c(2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.05), AWF = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), BGR = c(1.13, 
1.14, 1.14, 1.14, 1.15, 1.15), BIT = c(7.47, 7.47, 7.45, 7.45, 
7.4, 7.58), BLT = c(0.18, 0.19, 0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), CAV = c(4.55, 
4.59, 4.6, 4.55, 4.55, 4.5), CDI = c(0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 
0.35, 0.36), CEN = c(6.37, 6.53, 6.52, 6.5, 6.44, 6.4), CMO = c(2.96, 
2.96, 2.99, 2.99, 3, 3), CVT = c(2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1
), DPC = c(2.79, 2.8, 2.76, 2.76, 2.76, 2.69), EBO = c(4.54, 
4.52, 4.53, 4.55, 4.55, 4.55), EUT = c(12.35, 12.35, 12.35, 12.35, 
12.05, 12.05), FBU = c(6.6, 6.57, 6.5, 6.4, 6.44, 6.46), FCS = c(6.85, 
6.85, 6.85, 6.85, 6.85, 6.85), FCT = c(5.17, 5.15, 5.14, 5.12, 
5.15, 5.15), FIN = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), FNZ = c(1.46, 1.46, 1.47, 
1.47, 1.48, 1.48), FPH = c(3.28, 3.23, 3.18, 3.24, 3.23, 3.17
), FRE = c(3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.11, 3.1), GFF = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), GLL = c(0.85, 
0.84, 0.84, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85), GMT = c(1.14, 1.14, 1.15, 1.15, 
1.14, 1.15), GPG = c(2.21, 2.23, 2.22, 2.19, 2.21, 2.25), GXH = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.12, 0.13), HBY = c(6.4, 6.45, 6.46, 6.5, 6.6, 
6.5), HED = c(4.2, 4.25, 4.25, 4.22, 4.22, 4.22), HLG = c(3.8, 
3.75, 3.77, 3.75, 3.73, 3.61), IFT = c(3.36, 3.45, 3.45, 3.45, 
3.42, 3.4), JFJ = c(5.3, 5.3, 5.3, 5.3, 5.3, 5.35), JMO = c(11.35, 
11.35, 11.35, 11.38, 11.4, 11.65), KFL = c(1.04, 1.04, 1.07, 
1.08, 1.08, 1.09), KIP = c(1.13, 1.12, 1.15, 1.16, 1.15, 1.12
), KRK = c(2.28, 2.28, 2.26, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3), LPC = c(1.75, 1.73, 
1.75, 1.77, 1.88, 1.86), MCK = c(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.59, 0.6, 0.59
), MDZ = c(2.43, 2.47, 2.48, 2.48, 2.48, 2.45), MET = c(3.46, 
3.45, 3.45, 3.45, 3.45, 3.45), MFT = c(2.3, 2.35, 2.38, 2.34, 
2.32, 2.32), MGL = c(1.12, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.2, 1.2), MHI = c(8.22, 
8.2, 8.14, 8, 8.05, 8), MOW = c(1.62, 1.62, 1.62, 1.62, 1.62, 
1.62), MVN = c(1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.64, 1.64, 1.6), MZY = c(4.44, 
4.45, 4.48, 4.48, 4.5, 4.5), NPT = c(0.99, 0.98, 0.98, 0.99, 
1, 1), NPX = c(5.94, 5.95, 5.95, 5.9, 5.84, 5.9), NTH = c(2.95, 
2.95, 2.96, 2.96, 2.96, 2.99), NTL = c(0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
0.1, 0.1), NWF = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), NZF = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.41, 0.42, 0.42, 0.41), NZO = c(1.08, 
1.11, 1.13, 1.12, 1.11, 1.1), NZR = c(31, 30.1, 30.95, 30.55, 
30.9, 30.8), NZX = c(9.2, 9.3, 9.38, 9.35, 9.35, 9.29), OZY = c(2.3, 
2.28, 2.28, 2.28, 2.3, 2.3), PBG = c(3.45, 3.39, 3.33, 3.44, 
3.4, 3.4), PCT = c(0.91, 0.91, 0.92, 0.92, 0.91, 0.91), PEB = c(0.28, 
0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28), PFI = c(1.04, 1.05, 1.05, 1.04, 
1.04, 1.03), PGC = c(4.01, 4.1, 4.15, 4.15, 4.15, 4.02), PGW = c(2.15, 
2.18, 2.2, 2.21, 2.2, 2.18), PIL = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02), POT = c(5.59, 5.58, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 5.45), PPG = c(0.84, 
0.84, 0.83, 0.84, 0.86, 0.85), PPL = c(2.76, 2.72, 2.69, 2.65, 
2.61, 2.7), PPP = c(0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.14), RBC = c(1.06, 
1.06, 1.05, 1.06, 1.06, 1.05), RBD = c(1.28, 1.28, 1.28, 1.28, 
1.28, 1.28), RNS = c(0.94, 0.99, 1.03, 1.04, 1, 1.01), RYM = c(3.65, 
3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.68, 3.64), SAN = c(4.55, 4.5, 4.6, 4.6, 4.55, 
4.51), SCT = c(3.25, 3.19, 3.1, 3.2, 3.21, 3.25), SCY = c(0.83, 
0.84, 0.84, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83), SEA = c(0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 
0.07, 0.07), SEK = c(4.9, 4.9, 4.8, 4.92, 4.92, 4.92), SKC = c(5.43, 
5.48, 5.45, 5.41, 5.5, 5.22), SKL = c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 
1.25, 1.25), SKT = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), SLG = c(0.39, 0.4, 0.39, 0.38, 0.39, 0.39
), SPN = c(1.29, 1.29, 1.26, 1.29, 1.29, 1.28), SPY = c(0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08), STU = c(4.74, 4.76, 4.85, 4.8, 
4.74, 4.72), TCL = c(5.85, 5.99, 5.99, 5.99, 6.02, 6), TEL = c(6.25, 
6.23, 6.23, 6.2, 6.23, 6.2), TEM = c(4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.55, 4.55, 
4.55), TEN = c(2.18, 2.18, 2.19, 2.18, 2.19, 2.18), THL = c(2.09, 
2.1, 2.09, 2.09, 2.15, 2.15), TLS = c(5.36, 5.36, 5.35, 5.4, 
5.42, 5.42), TNZ = c(1.19, 1.19, 1.2, 1.19, 1.2, 1.19), TPW = c(5.7, 
5.6, 5.61, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6), TRS = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), TTK = c(2.6, 2.6, 2.63, 2.64, 
2.55, 2.55), TUA = c(4.22, 4.15, 4.16, 4.2, 4.15, 4.15), TUR = c(3, 
3, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1), TWR = c(2.14, 2.14, 2.11, 2.08, 2.08, 2.06
), VCT = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), VHP = c(0.99, 0.99, 1, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99), VIL = c(0.85, 
0.85, 0.9, 0.86, 0.85, 0.84), WBC = c(18.32, 18.32, 18.32, 18.32, 
18.32, 18.32), WDT = c(0.58, 0.53, 0.58, 0.54, 0.5, 0.5), WHS = c(3.71, 
3.77, 3.72, 3.69, 3.66, 3.63), AUG = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), BRM = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), BRM.1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), DGL = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HFL = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), RAK = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), TPI = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), AORWA = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), DIL = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MLN = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), OGC = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), OIC = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), XRO = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CUE = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), KIPGC = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), KMD = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), DNZ = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), TIL = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CNU = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HNZ = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MAD = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), SUM = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), TME = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MOA = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), NTLOA = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), FSF = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), JMOOA = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("Date", 
"ABA", "ACY", "AFI", "AIA", "AIR", "ALF", "AMP", "ANZ", "AOR", 
"APN", "ARG", "ASBPA", "ASBPB", "ATM", "ATR", "AWF", "BGR", "BIT", 
"BLT", "CAV", "CDI", "CEN", "CMO", "CVT", "DPC", "EBO", "EUT", 
"FBU", "FCS", "FCT", "FIN", "FNZ", "FPH", "FRE", "GFF", "GLL", 
"GMT", "GPG", "GXH", "HBY", "HED", "HLG", "IFT", "JFJ", "JMO", 
"KFL", "KIP", "KRK", "LPC", "MCK", "MDZ", "MET", "MFT", "MGL", 
"MHI", "MOW", "MVN", "MZY", "NPT", "NPX", "NTH", "NTL", "NWF", 
"NZF", "NZO", "NZR", "NZX", "OZY", "PBG", "PCT", "PEB", "PFI", 
"PGC", "PGW", "PIL", "POT", "PPG", "PPL", "PPP", "RBC", "RBD", 
"RNS", "RYM", "SAN", "SCT", "SCY", "SEA", "SEK", "SKC", "SKL", 
"SKT", "SLG", "SPN", "SPY", "STU", "TCL", "TEL", "TEM", "TEN", 
"THL", "TLS", "TNZ", "TPW", "TRS", "TTK", "TUA", "TUR", "TWR", 
"VCT", "VHP", "VIL", "WBC", "WDT", "WHS", "AUG", "BRM", "BRM.1", 
"DGL", "HFL", "RAK", "TPI", "AORWA", "DIL", "MLN", "OGC", "OIC", 
"XRO", "CUE", "KIPGC", "KMD", "DNZ", "TIL", "CNU", "HNZ", "MAD", 
"SUM", "TME", "MOA", "NTLOA", "FSF", "JMOOA"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The line `aggregate(data, as.yearmon, tail, 1)` doesn't make much sense.  What's the result from that?  And could you also post a few lines of the data with `dput(head(stockdata))`

Comment: `aggregate` is probably returning a data.frame. You might  need to index `mprices` with `[,2]`

Comment: hi richard, the aggregate line was used to convert to monthly prices from daily price values.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of missing info in your question.  Are you using the `zoo` and `xts` packages?  And why are there two functions in your `aggregate` call? Have  a read of `?aggregate` it seems you're using it incorrectly

Comment: The problem with this data example is that there is only one month in the mprices object. You need to supply an example with more than one month if you want to calculate differences between months.